# Debug.log File Appearing

Tags: html, google-chrome, debugging

When I open index.html to run my website, a Debug.log file appears saying the following message in the screenshot.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEF3r.png)
This only happens when I run index.html using Google Chrome, **no other browser does that**. This does not affect the way the website runs, however I find it annoying that I get this log file appearing every time.

I run the website locally, and this what index.html contains.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Frames</title>
</head>
<FRAMESET Cols = "20%,80%">
<FRAME SRC="menu.html" Name="left" Scrolling="Yes" Noresize>
<FRAME SRC="start.html" Name="main" Scrolling="Yes" Noresize>
</FRAMESET>
</html>
```

Comment: could I see the index.html? which server do you use?

Comment: You have two accounts with @vangelis7? Asking because of the suggested edit.